# Removing a node from a linked list using recursion java

Tags: java, list, recursion, linked-list

So i have a linked list that I want to be able to remove the first occurrence of a number,

I'm trying to use recursion but sadly all I end up doing is being able to delete the head of the list and

```
public List remove(int num){
   if(value == num) {
       return next.remove(value);
   }else{
       next = next.remove(value);
       return this;
   }
}
```

I know i need to return the new list, but how exactly do i either get rid of the node that I'm trying to avoid or is there a way to work around it, so it continues to the next nod.

Edit. Update on the actual code.

```
class List{
  int value;  //value at this node 
  List next;  //reference to next object in list
  public List(int value, List next){
      this.value = value;
      this.next  = next;
  }
}
```

I have three different classes, one for the empty list at the end of this, and a class declaring this method, and the actual list.

```
  public static List makeSample() {
        EmptyList e = new EmptyList();
        List l1 = new List(5, e);
        List l2 = new List(4, l1);
        List l3 = new List(3, l2);
        List l4 = new List(3, l3);
        List l5 = new List(2, l4);
        List l6 = new List(1, l5);
        return l6;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to create a copy of the list without the element, or change the list inplace?

Comment: Create a copy of the list without the element.

Comment: Can you clarify what List you are using? Is it a `java.util.List` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or something of your own? Where are the variables `value` and `next` coming from? You say you want to return a copy of the list, but in fact you are just returning the same reference `this`.

Comment: I tried to answer this question but I realized I don't know enough about how your implementation is structured exactly.

Comment: @user1832483 First, I believe you are using your own `List` structure and not the `java.util.List`. So can you please post code complete class definition for the `List` class.

Comment: @user1832483  Second, when you say that you want to create a copy of the list, do you wish to create a new list, so that all the elements in the original list, except the removed element, appear twice in memory.

Comment: @Ankit When i implemented the code the first time I was able to keep the list I originally made, and then had a second list without the first number before this list I had {1,3,1,4,5}. I was able to get rid of the first 1 but if I put it in the middle of the list I just get back an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class List {

    private int value;
    private List next;

    public static final List EMPTY = new List(-1, null) {
        public List remove(int n) { return this; };
        public String toString() { return ""; };
    };

    public List(int value, List next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public List remove(int n) {
        if (value == n) return next;
        return new List(value,next.remove(n));
    }   

    public String toString() {
        return value + "," + next.toString();
    }

    public static class Examples {

        @Test
        public void shouldRemoveElement() {
            List l = new List(1, new List(2, new List(2, new List(3, EMPTY))));
            assertEquals("1,2,2,3,",l.toString());
            assertEquals("2,2,3,",l.remove(1).toString());
            assertEquals("1,2,3,",l.remove(2).toString());
            assertEquals("1,2,2,",l.remove(3).toString());
            assertEquals("1,2,2,3,",l.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tryed implementing your code, maybe im not following right but why exactly are you using next.value, don't you have put .get before value to be able to compare them?

Comment: In Java, fields are class private, that is an instance can access the private fields of another instance of the same class. (Did the code compile for you?)

Comment: no the code wouldn't compile saying it cannot find the symbol variable value which doesn't make sense to me because its declared in the constructor.

Comment: So how exactly is the code working? I havent learned the null ? null code yet so that's throwing me off.

Comment: `null` works the same way as your EmptyList. Actually using EmptyList is smarter, it is called a nullobject. Google for Nullobject Pattern to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Keep two lists.

```
List nonDuplicates;

List allElements;

for (Node node : allElements){
    if (!nonDuplicates.contains(node)){
        nonDuplicates.add(node);
    }
}
```